# Trying to merge two arrays

Tags: javascript

Below is my json stored in :

```
$scope.regions = [];

{
  "id": 100,
  "regions": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Abc",
      "rank": 0,
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "name": "Pqr",
      "rank": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "name": "Lmn",
      "rank": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 40,
      "name": "xyz",
      "rank": 3,
    },
    {
      "id": 50,
      "name": "GGG",
      "rank": 4,
    },
    {
      "id": 60,
      "name": "YYY",
      "rank": 5,
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my another json stored in :

```
$scope.regionList = [];
var highestOrder = 3;

  "regions": [
    {
      "id": 40,
      "name": "xyz",
      "rank": 0,
    },
    {
      "id": 50,
      "name": "GGG",
      "rank": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 60,
      "name": "YYY",
      "rank": 2,
    }
```

Now I want to merge $scope.regionList in to $scope.regions but for those records which are matching in both $scope.regionList and $scope.regions I would like to replace records of $scope.regions with $scope.regionList (only common records from both list).

And first non matching records from $scope.regionList will have order start using highestOrder and will keep incrementing for each non-matching records so final output will be like below :

**Expected output :**

```
"regions": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Abc",
      "rank": 3,
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "name": "Pqr",
      "rank": 4,
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "name": "Lmn",
      "rank": 5,
    },
    {
      "id": 40,
      "name": "xyz",
      "rank": 0,
    },
    {
      "id": 50,
      "name": "GGG",
      "rank": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 60,
      "name": "YYY",
      "rank": 2,
    }
```

As Abc is is the first non matching record so it will have order 3 and rest other will have order no from 3 i.e 4,5 6, etc.

**My code:**

```
var highestOrder = 3;
 var found = false;

 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.regions.length; i++) {
   if ($scope.regions[i].id == 100) {
       found = true;
       for (var j = 0; j < $scope.regionList.length; j++) {
          for (var k = 0; k < $scope.regions[i].regions.length; k++) {
           if ($scope.regions[i].regions[k].id == $scope.regionList[j].id) {
                   $scope.regions[i].regions[k].rank = $scope.regionList[j].rank;
             } 
            else {
                   $scope.regions[i].regions[k].rank = highestOrder;
                    highestOrder = highestOrder + 1;
                 }
         }
     }
  }
  if (found)
       break;
}
```

```js
var regions = {
  "id": 100,
  "regions": [{
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Abc",
      "rank": 0,
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "name": "Pqr",
      "rank": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "name": "Lmn",
      "rank": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 40,
      "name": "xyz",
      "rank": 3,
    },
    {
      "id": 50,
      "name": "GGG",
      "rank": 4,
    },
    {
      "id": 60,
      "name": "YYY",
      "rank": 5,
    }
  ]
}
var highestOrder = 3;
var found = false;
var regionList = [{
    "id": 40,
    "name": "xyz",
    "rank": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 50,
    "name": "GGG",
    "rank": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 60,
    "name": "YYY",
    "rank": 2
  }
]

for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
  if (regions[i].id == 100) {
    found = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < regionList.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < regions[i].regions.length; k++) {
        if (regions[i].regions[k].id == regionList[j].id) {
          regions[i].regions[k].rank = regionList[j].rank;
        } else {
          regions[i].regions[k].rank = highestOrder;
          highestOrder = highestOrder + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (found)
    break;
}
console.log(regions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table and build it with the elements of the array for updating.

Then iterate `regions` and update `rank` with either the hash's `rank` or with `highestOrder`. Increment `highestOrder` after assigning.

```js
var $scope = { regions: [{ id: 100, regions: [{ id: 10, name: "Abc", rank: 0, }, { id: 20, name: "Pqr", rank: 1, }, { id: 30, name: "Lmn", rank: 2, }, { id: 40, name: "xyz", rank: 3, }, { id: 50, name: "GGG", rank: 4, }, { id: 60, name: "YYY", rank: 5, }] }] },
    regionsUpdate = [{ id: 40, name: "xyz", rank: 0, }, { id: 50, name: "GGG", rank: 1, }, { id: 60, name: "YYY", rank: 2, }],
    regionsId = 100,
    highestOrder = 3,
    hash = Object.create(null);

regionsUpdate.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.id] = a;
});

$scope.regions.some(function (a) {
    if (a.id === regionsId) {
        a.regions.forEach(function (b) {
            b.rank = hash[b.id] ? hash[b.id].rank : highestOrder++;
        });
        return true;
    }
});

console.log($scope);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.I am having multiple regions with Id=100 and 101 so if i want to this for region id= 100 then?

Comment: what happens with `highestOrder` for `id = 101`?

Comment: I will have Region list for each region with id =100,101 and highest order will come for only for 1 region  at a time.so right now
i would like to consider for only regiion = 100

Comment: When i run your solution seperately it is working fine but it is not working in angular js as $scope.regions. is angular js variable so this variable is not getting update and i am really not getting why this is not working

Comment: i am sory about angular. i don't know it.

Comment: Your solution worked.I remember that you have also help me before.Thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this :)

Comment: Just 1 question that what does this $scope.regions.some(function (a) line do??

Comment: [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) iterates the array and stops the iteration with returning `true`, if the right `id` is found. i thought, if found, then apply ranking and exit the loop.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again.I am not getting this line :hash[b.id] ? hash[b.id].rank : highestOrder++;Can you tell me something about this please.what will be the equivalent if condition for this

Comment: it is a ternary of `if (hash[b.id]) { b.rank = hash[b.id].rank; } else { b.rank = highestOrder++; }`